I want to obtain a tensor with all possible combination of the rows of a matrix in Torch
I have a tensor of 4 dimensions let#s call them N,T,V,C, now I would like to have a tensor of dimension N,T,C^V, or better N,T,C,C,...,C for V times, where the elements are the outher products of the V,C matrix rows for each N,T. I am in a nn.module enviroment with parameters associated so I have to use torch functions and all needed to then be able to do the gradient of the parameters.
Thanks
I can do it like this
X = torch.rand((1000,,2,10))
Y = X.view(-1, X.shape[2], X.shape[3])
Z = []
for i in Y:
    comb = [j for j in i]
    Z.append(torch.sum(torch.tensor(list(itertools.product(*comb))),dim=1))

where before stacking I sum the elements of the vector of combinations, which is a plus but not needed. it works but not in the layer enviroment with parameters.

Not entirely sure on the specific operation you are trying to do but a vectorized approach would be to separate into two tensors of shape N,T,C,1 and N,T,1,V, then expand each to shapes N,T,C,V and N,T,C,V. Do your operation on these tensors, and the result at position, ,,c,v will correspond to that operation performed on the cth row and vth column from the matrix corresponding to the last two dimensions from the original tensor. You can then view this in whatever dimension you want (e.g. N,T,C*V)
